# Find out all users who accessed SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to find out who are all users who accessed specific database during specific time in sql server?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I use it every time

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(100) = 'test'
DECLARE @AllConnections TABLE(
    SPID INT,
    Status VARCHAR(MAX),
    LOGIN VARCHAR(MAX),
    HostName VARCHAR(MAX),
    BlkBy VARCHAR(MAX),
    DBName VARCHAR(MAX),
    Command VARCHAR(MAX),
    CPUTime INT,
    DiskIO INT,
    LastBatch VARCHAR(MAX),
    ProgramName VARCHAR(MAX),
    SPID_1 INT,
    REQUESTID INT
)

INSERT INTO @AllConnections EXEC sp_who2

SELECT * FROM @AllConnections WHERE DBName = @DatabaseName
```